# Can I get a compiler/Xcode 'warning' when not releasing a retained object in the class dealloc method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have been using AppCode recently to circumvent an issue with Xcode in refactoring, and AppCode has nailed for me quite few "oups'es" whereby it warned me of un-released but retained object refs ... sniffing them out correctly through @property specifications too ! (not exactly what I was looking for mind you :) ), but a great help.

I was wondering if such a feature is available in Xcode (am using 4.1.1), and if yes how/where to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform that kind of check using static analyzer - choose "Analyze" option from Product menu (or shift-cmd-B shortcut)

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, Analysis is systematically 'on' when I build, but it actually missed such an error (i re-infected my code with the same error AppCode had sniffed). Are there analyser 'settings' that i can set to increased its sensitivity to my clumsiness ?

Comment: Fed up, i finally switched to AppCode. Every version of Xcode is worse than the one before.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the mode of analysis for 'Build' to deep under project build settings. By default its set to shallow.

Its located under the heading '**Static Analyzer - Analysis Policy**'

Comment: thanks @clicknow. That question was old news !!! since then, xCode sucks more than back then, and AppCode is even better than it was then. Guess which IDE i am using.